# What is the motivation of data updaters in chainlink?

Tags: oracles, chainlink

I wondered how chainlink works then I realized its price feeds like ETH/USD are updating periodically.
if I get it right, the nodes have to update data in most blockchains continuously, which costs a lot. here is my question what is their motivation and why are they spending so much money and what is their benefit?

Answer (score 0):

The native token used on the oracle chain will be the incentive. Hardware, data transfer - these all cost in fiat. Some one off costs, some reoccurring.

Although there is no guarantee of it, there is an expectation that the tokens provided in return for maintaining the oracle will appreciate in value and cover running costs.

Some token holders will sell to subsidize monthly costs and keep the rest but it's all personal preference.

Comment: tnx but I mean chainlink updates data on all blockchains on multiple contracts and it costs on eth, bnb, matic, etc. how chainlink pays this money it costs alot

Comment: There isn't just one person running a node or updating data. The cost to use the platform is paid in whatever token the chain requires. The rules that determine how much actions cost are always varying. Users will still have to buy tokens with fiat to participate, so this provides liquidity to the market.

Comment: I still don't get it. the update fee must be paid. for the contract on the Ethereum blockchain, the fee for updating data must be paid every 1 minute. who pays for it? and the node that updates the data in this scale what will get in return? How will the fee paid for the update be compensated?